# swi prolog unified return elements in list

Tags: prolog, logic

I want to return all elements in a list like the result below in X

```
?return_list_members([1,2,3,4,5], X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5.
```

I have the following code but it **also returns** the empty list element [] witch **is not desirable**.

```
return_member(X, X).
return_list_members([], []).
return_list_members([H|T], X) :- return_member(H, X); return_list_members(T, X).
```

output when questioned

```
?return_list_members([1,2,3,4,5], X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5 ;
X = [].
```

also the **true or false at the end** values are not desirable at the end.

The goal is to achieve a function witch **outputs like the built-in function between/3** to be **used in a foreach** statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the procedure you are trying to write is the builtin predicate member/2.

```
?- member(X, [1,2,3,4,5]).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5.
```

You can also write your own definition, e.g.:

```
return_list_members([X|_], X).
return_list_members([_|T], X):-
  return_list_members(T, X).
```

and if you don't want the interpreter to return 'false' at the end, you can add another clause at the beginning (as the first clause):

```
return_list_members([X], X):- !.
```

Note however that this clause will have side effects if you call this procedure with the first parameter uninstantiated.

Comment: i was not aware member had that capability, although both answers turned out to be very helpful since i have to do other routines similar to this one.

Comment: instead of your use of `cut/0` please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436568/code-for-member-2-with-some-determinism/8437359#8437359) to achieve determinism on the last element. It's what's used in swi and doesn't destruct any behavior.

Comment: @mog: that is SWI's implementation of member, that OP should use; and the determinism in that predicate is just a trick (i doubt it will work on every prolog implementation)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write between_/3:

```
between_(X, X, X) :-
    !.
between_(X, Y, X) :-
    X < Y.
between_(X, Y, N) :-
    X < Y,
    T is X + 1,
    between_(T, Y, N).
```

The first clause it's required to avoid the final false (as already noticed by gusbro).