# Prolog function iscontained?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm trying to make a Prolog predicate `iscontained/2`: `iscontained(List, Search)` where it returns `true.` if the `Search` is listed within the given `List`, `false.` if not. And if it is a variable that is inputted, then it just returns that it equals each element in the list.

Example:

```
?- iscontained([a, b, c], a).

true.

?- iscontained([a, b, c], d).

false.

?- iscontained([a, b, c], A).

A = a;
A = b;
A = c;
false.
```

I need a shove in the right direction, not asking for a hand out, unless you know a quick way to do it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: btw the `member/2` predicate does just that, although with switched parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to consider two cases. I'll leave the body of the rules up to you.

- `iscontained([A|Xs],A)`
- `iscontained([X|Xs],A)`

[edited to remove reference to the empty list: the empty list contains nothing: if encountered, the predicate fails.]

Comment: the first case isn't required

Comment: @Mog: I left the mention of the first case there, as you do still need to *consider* it, even though you probably won't end up with a rule for it.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the frequently proposed `member/2` predicate admits solutions that are no lists at all:

```
?- member(e,[e|nonlist]).
   true.
```

This is not a big problem in many situations, but should be mentioned nevertheless.

A natural, symmetric definition that only admits lists uses DCGs:

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .

iscontained(Es, E) :-
   phrase((...,[E],...), Es).
```

The `...` is a non-terminal which denotes an arbitrary sequence.

While this is entirely overkill for this tiny example, it gives you a template for more interesting patterns.  Like

```
iscontainedtwice(Es, E) :-
   phrase((...,[E],...,[E],...), Es).
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that you certainly already came up with a solution, I'd like to mention one thing:

The classical version:

```
member(Item, [Item|_List]).
member(Item, [_Head|List]) :- member(Item, List).
```

leaves a choice point after having found the last element possible, ie:

```
?- member(A, [1, 2, 3]).
A = 1;
A = 2;
A = 3;
false.
```

while

```
member2(Item, [Head|List]) :-
    member2(List, Item, Head).

member2(_List, Item, Item).
member2([Head|List], Item, _PreviousHead) :-
    member2(List, Item, Head).
```

treats the empty list at the same time as the last element and allows optimization:

```
?- member2(A, [1, 2, 3]).
A = 1;
A = 2;
A = 3.
```

That's the version used in SWI-Prolog (and certainly Jekejeke Prolog and maybe others). Its author is Gertjan van Noord.

That's just meant as a reminder that, while the exercise of coming up yourself with a `member/2` implementation is excellent, it should not lead you not use the built-ins afterwards, they're often fine tuned and more efficient!

Comment: Yep, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436568/code-for-member-2-with-some-determinism